# Refresh data for entire application after changing connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a application with `LinkButton` in master page which is used to change the `database` for application. I am changing `connection string` in `web.config` file based on this buttons text. The code for `LinkButton` click is:

```
if (LinkButton.Text == "Switch To Country1 Site")
{
    LinkButton.Text = "Switch To Country2 Site";
    Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    ConnectionStringsSection sec = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
    sec.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=Source; Initial Catalog=database1; Integrated Security=true";
    config.Save();
}
else
{
    LinkButton.Text = "Switch To Country1 Site";
    Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    ConnectionStringsSection sec = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
    sec.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=Source; Initial Catalog=database2; Integrated Security=true";
    config.Save();
}
```

I am setting this connection string to my `DataHelper` from `Application_Start` in `Global.asax` file. I also tried to reload the application from here(don't know if it is good idea or not) to refresh content but its not working. Like:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DatabaseHelper.ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString;
    //To reload application...
    System.Web.HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();
}
```

My connection string is changing successfully but the problem is that the application data not refreshing. For example in my application I have some `gridviews` that display data from database but their data not updating based on `database` selected(`connection string`).

> EDIT: Now, I think it will not work for multiple users as i am
>   changing `web.config`. Is there any way I can change
>   `connectionString` with `session variable` for specific user on button
>   click..

Any help regarding this will be appreciated. (sorry for the dumb code..) If you can suggest a better way to achieve this that will be great. Thank You..!!

Comment: @Amit, Thanks for suggestion I have no idea about how to use singleton classe. I bind gridview on first load of page

Comment: Profile settings, which are generally used to store selected theme for the user.

Comment: Can you plz provide an example how to change database in that. Thanks

Comment: Your code need to take care of re-loading the data in controls when the connection string changes. Application won't do it by itself. Also you need to understand that if you are changing the connection string in the configuration it will impact all the users who are using the application. So if user1 changes the country selection it will be reflected to the other users of the application too. Do you want the connection string change applicable only to the user who changes the country selection?

Comment: Yes @Chetan I noticed it now, I only wanna change it for one user who click the button

Comment: Can you share the code which uses the connection string from config file to query data from the database?

Comment: As i am passing connection string to helper class on Application_Start so in my webform only use this: using (var db = new DatabaseHelper())
            {
                using (var ds = db.ExecDataSet(Queries.GetAllReminders))
                {//Use data}}   If you need more info plz ask